# OpenGL, Send matrix to vertex shader and display GLSL

Tags: arrays, opengl, matrix, glsl, shader

Im trying to create a mesh of z = y^2 - x^2 for a uni assessment. Ive create a matrix array to that hold the sqaures that i want to draw as `GL_LINE_STRIPS` called `sqaureMatrix[100]`. What i want to know is how i can send that to a vertex shader and display it.

i will put some code below that says how ive set things up so far

**asessment.cpp**

```
mat4 squareMatrix[100];

// this is in general how i fill the matrix

mat4 pseudo = mat4

(
vec4(1,1,1,1),
vec4(1,1,1,1),
vec4(1,1,1,1),
vec4(1,1,1,1)
);

// loop through and actually add to the squarematrix like

squareMatrix[0] = pseudo;
```

**vshader.glsl**

```
uniform mat4 mMatrix;


void
main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        gl_Position = mMatrix[i];
    }
}
```

Well you get the jist of it. The matrix is set up fine. I thought I would just add it to clarify some things.

Comment: In most profiles, vertex shaders are only required to support 1024 uniform components. An array of 100 `mat4`s uses 1600. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, but that certainly cannot be it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already have the array. So you point OpenGL to it by passing it as a *Vertex Array* (or you copy it onto a *Vertex Buffer Object* which is then referenced as Vertex Array). Google for those terms to understand what they do. They're part of every modern OpenGL tutorial. Then you make OpenGL draw from that data.

As it happens I only recently added a [minimal VBO example to my codesamples GitHub repository](https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalvbo), in response to another StackOverflow question. It matches your question as well.